# date range filter in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

Date filter not working in django view page, I need it for getting records in between an date range.

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2015, 1, 30)
enquiryList = ModelName.objects.filter(dateposted=(start_date,end_date))
```

If any files has to be imported to run this query. Please send your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `__range` lookup:

```
enquiryList = ModelName.objects.filter(dateposted__range=(start_date,end_date))
```